# intellisense with razor and VS 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, razor, webmatrix

Is there any way to get intellisense with razor in VS 2010, I am working on an application with web matrix and launched VS 2010 from WebMatrix.

Comment: Hooray: Question is not longer relevant: Just install the current ASP.NET MVC release. Nothing personal (you have my +1) but now I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, wait, patiently - intellisense support and other VS integration is coming according to the Gu

**Update 28th July 2010**

Scott has posted about MVC 3 here: [Introducing ASP.NET MVC 3 (Preview 1)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx)

Which, amongst a lot of other interesting stuff, contains the following:

---

Code Intellisense and Colorization

One of the things you might have noticed from the screen-shots above is that “Razor” file colorization and code intellisense is not yet supported in Visual Studio with today’s “Preview 1” release.  We will be enabling full code intellisense and colorization with a future preview refresh.  The VS 2010 editor will support Razor file intellisense for C#/VB code, as well as for HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

---